# Cats, reducing a Seq of EitherT

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, reduction, either

I am working on a project where I discovered the cats's `EitherT` type. In one of my tasks I would like to reduce a `Seq` of of producer of `EitherT[Future, L, R]` to an `EitherT[Future, L, Seq[R]]` when they are all *right*. And to abort the reduction and return the failed `LeftT[Future, L, Seq[R]]` otherwise.

I have a successful reduction for the happy path with the following code:

```
type Producer = () => EitherT[Future, L, Seq[R]] // where L and R are known types.
private def execute(producers:Seq[Producer]):EitherT[Future, L, Seq[R]] = {
  producers match {
    case last :: Nil =>
      last()
    case current :: nexts =>
      current().flatMap(res => execute(nexts).map(res ++ _))
   } 
}
```

But I cannot find a clean way to handle a `LefT`. Do you have any tips on how to handle the left case on my reduction ?

Thanks

**Edit**: because it may not be clear enough.

My input is a `Seq[Producer]` (A `Producer` give an `EitherT` when it is applied). I want to apply and reduce my producers to one `EitherT` but I have to abort the process if one producer fail (returns one `EitherT` which hold a `Left`).

Given :

- `P1`, `P2` and `P3`, three producers that returns a `Right` `EitherT`, respectively `Seq(A)`, `Seq(B)` and `Seq(C, D)`
- Reduction of `Seq(P1, P2, P3)` will return an `EitherT` of a `Right(Seq(A, B, C, D))`.

Given:

- `P1` and `P3`, two producers that returns a `Right` `EitherT`, respectively `Seq(A)` and `Seq(C, D)`
- `P2` one producer returning a `Left("fail")
- Reduction of `Seq(P1, P2, P3)` will return an `EitherT` of a `Left("fail")`.

**Edit 2:**
Another possibility is to *fold* the producers bu the result looks more or less the same (and the accumulation of passed producers is less clean) :

```
var history = Seq.empty[]
val empty = //..
producers.foldLeft(empty) {
  case (left, producer) =>
    history :+ producer // May be in history while failed
    producer().flatMap(i => left.map(_ + i))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .sequence

```scala
  import cats.implicits._

  val success = List(
    EitherT.right[Int](Option("1")),
    EitherT.right[Int](Option("2")))

  println(success.sequence) // EitherT(Some(Right(List(1, 2))))

  val error = success :+ EitherT.left[String](Option(3))

  println(error.sequence) // EitherT(Some(Left(1)))
```

Comment: I fear that my question was not clear enough. I want to reduce my `Seq[Producer]` as `EitherT` but I cannot apply a `Producer` if the previous failed.